# Select maximum value in column based on conditions of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
 UG        S Sample Type        Moment
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>
1 84        9 S08    Girder 1 0.407    
2 84        9 S08    Girder 2 0.330    
3 84        9 S08    Girder 1 0.0000486
4 84        9 S08    Girder 4 0.363    
5 84        9 S08    Girder 5 0.443    
6 84        9 S09    Girder 1 0.409
```

I want to create a subset dataframe such that for the rows that have columns `UG, S, Sample, Type` in common, the row with maximum value in `Moment` is selected and the rest of removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(UG, S, Sample, Type) %>% summarise(Moment = max(Moment))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'UG', 'S', 'Sample' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   UG, S, Sample [2]
     UG     S Sample Type     Moment
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
1    84     9 S08    Girder 1  0.407
2    84     9 S08    Girder 2  0.33 
3    84     9 S08    Girder 4  0.363
4    84     9 S08    Girder 5  0.443
5    84     9 S09    Girder 1  0.409
>
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `base R`

```
aggregate(Moment ~ UG + S + Sample + Type, df, FUN = max)
```